# I tried this code but get error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" In titleForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

i'm Using MRC(do not use ARC)

section.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* headerTitle;
```

section.m

```
- (instancetype)initwhithHeaderTitle:(NSString *)headerTitle {
    self.headerTitle = headerTitle;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    self.headerTitle = nil;
}
```

tableview.m

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.sections[section].headerTitle;
}
```

but scroll than error BAD ACCESS. Helpme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your headerTitle is `assign` it is same as **weak**  , You must keep it **retain**

Replace your code

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* headerTitle;
```

with

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* headerTitle;
```

**EDIT**

---

non ARC you need to use . `release`

Comment: Thank's your answer, but i'm using MRC version. replace with a `retain`?  when calling release?

Comment: I have only idea about ARC , as per me `retain` is a good to use and  if you are not using ARC then you need to manually `release` object `nil` will not work here :)